# System of differential equations - Equilibria, phase plane, polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, differential

I am currently studying for my exam in ordinary differential equations and I am having a hard time with the following problem:

I have given the system of ODEs:

$$
x^\prime = x+xy-(x+y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \\
y^\prime = y-x^2+(x-y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.
$$

I already transformed the system in polar coordinates, which looks like:
$$
r^\prime=r(1-r), \theta^\prime=(1- \text{cos }\theta)r
$$

My first problem: I have to determine the equilibrium points but I don't know how to do it in polar coordinates. How do I get the quilibrium points in polar coordinates and how are they in relation with the system in $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

My second problem: I have to sketch a phase plane and I have no clue how to do it in polar coordinates.

Please help me out.

Comment: First. Variable separable integration for $ r,\theta $ and plot it.

Comment: So I have to seperate the first equation like this: $\int\frac{1}{r(1-r}\text{d}r= \int 1 \text{d}t$ and the same thing for $\theta^\prime$? Did I get it right? What do I get from this and what should I do as the next step?

Comment: HINT To start divide by dt to eliminate t ; $\int \frac{dr}{1-r}=\int \frac{d \theta}{1-\cos\theta}$

Comment: @Moo yes I double checked it, it is correct.

Comment: @Narasimham this confuses me even more. Why are these integrals equal?

Comment: This helps me but there is something that bothers me. In my case $\theta^\prime$ ist dependant of r, which confuses me a lot. How can I handle this? And am I right, that $(0,0)$ is the only equilibrium point which is not stable. $(1,2k\pi), k\in\mathbb{R}$ is also a candidate for equilibrium, but I can see that this one is a limit cycle, i.e a circle with radius 1.

Comment: I have figured it out. It took a while for me to understand it

Comment: Is the answer now clearer to find limit cycles?

Answer (score 1):

After your conversion to polar coordinates

$$ r^\prime=r(1-r), \theta^\prime=(1- \text{cos }\theta)r $$

Divide to eliminate parameter

$$ \frac{dr}{1-r}= \frac{d \theta}{1-\cos \theta}$$

$$ - \log (1-r) = \cot \theta/2+ \text{constant}$$

$$ (1-r)= c\cdot e^{-cot (\theta/2)}$$

Note that the sign can be either positive or negative for initial/ boundary value point to be either inside limit cycle $r=1,c=0 $ or outside. In the limit  $ \; r\to 1. $

At  $\theta = \pi/4 $ for spirals inside or outside the limit unit circle....

if $  r_i<1 \text{ then } c>0  \text {  and if }\; r_i>1 \text{ then}  \; c<0 $

Points taken are $ (0,0.6), (0,1.25), (0,1.75)$ for limit cycle given below.

Phase portraits for state variables $(r,r')\;, (\theta,\theta')$ can be drawn.

[image]